# Websphere 8.5 CDI triggers Observer multiple Times

Tags: cdi, java-ee-6, websphere-8

I am using Websphere 8.5 and have a problem with a simple CDI event.

The emitting EJB is stateless and emits the event once. I tested it with a breakpoint in the pojos constructor so there are no other places where this event gets fired.

I already checked my imports, but I used the correct imports. Does anyone spot my error or am I just running in another bug? The CDI implementation seems to be pretty outdated.

I tested without the TransactionAttribute and outside the debug mode too. Does not change anything.

Thanks in advance!
m

```
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.event.TransactionPhase;

@Stateless
public class CreateService {
   // Injecting the emitter
   @Inject
   private Event<CreateEvent> createEmitter;

   public void create(String id) {
      // fire the create event
      CreateEvent event = new CreateEvent(id);
      createEmitter.fire(event);
   }

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void postCreate(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) CreateEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Received " + event.getId());
   }
}
```

Event producer and consumer is in the same EJB.

```
public class CreateEvent {
    private String id;


    public CreateEvent() {
    }

    public CreateEvent(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String id() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CreateEvent ["
                + (id != null ? "id=" + id
                        : "") + "]";
    }
}

[10/22/14 9:58:53:231 CEST] 000000a2 SystemOut     O   Received A622665
[10/22/14 9:58:53:231 CEST] 000000a2 SystemOut     O   Received A622665
[10/22/14 9:58:53:231 CEST] 000000a2 SystemOut     O   Received A622665
[10/22/14 9:58:53:246 CEST] 000000a2 SystemOut     O   Received A622665
[10/22/14 9:58:53:246 CEST] 000000a2 SystemOut     O   Received A622665
```

Comment: It runs fine on WAS 8.5.5.1. The `@TransactionAttribute` in observes method is obsolete, remove it. Are you sure that: 1) you fire only in one place? 2)you have only one class with @Observes method? (maybe it is in some parent/abstract class?)

Comment: Yes i only have one place where I trigger the event. @TransactionAttribute is not obsolete (imho), because the event is observed AFTER the commit. So I want to start a new one. On wildfly this was required. The reference of the CreateEvent is exactly the same for every invoke. Looks like a Websphere Bug to me. Works perfect on wildfly.

Comment: As I wrote, it works perfectly in 8.5.5.1. My listener is POJO not EJB, so TransactionAttribute is not considered then. Please add your full class that generates and receives event, and fragment how you call your business method.

Comment: That might be the problem that I use an EJB instead of a POJO! This was a very good tip to check. If you fill that into an answer I can mark it after my tests (hope i have the time till end of the week). Thanks a lot for your feedback!